# Every bounded lattice may or may not be finite.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, lattice-orders

I want an example of a bounded lattice which is infinite with hasse diagram. 
As finite lattice is a lattice which surely contains greatest and least element then what is infinite lattice. Please elaborate that also.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stackexchange. What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Consider the closed interval $[0,1]$ with the usual order.

Comment: @Berci $[0,1]$ doesn't have a Hasse diagram.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "lattice" in set theory???](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646832/what-is-a-lattice-in-set-theory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $0$, $x_i$ for $i$ natural, and $1$ be the elements of the lattice. $0<x_i<1$ for all $i$, and the $x_i$ are pairwise incomparable. This is a bounded infinite lattice that has a Hasse diagram. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: sir. It should be [0,1] for 0 to be the least element and 1 to be the greatest element for bounded lattice. I am confused why this is not a chain. I am stuck at drawing hasse diagram for this. Could you please show it's hasse diagram.

Comment: And what is infinite lattice. Is it a lattice with infinite elements containing greatest element and least element as well or there is some other definition for this. Please clarify it.

Comment: @mb14 It's not a chain because $x_i$ is incomparable to $x_j$ if $i\neq j$.

Comment: @mb14 I added an image.

Comment: Thank you Matt Samuel and @amrsa. But I am not able to find any number which are incomparable. Can you please tell me any real number example any x1, x2 in the set [0,1] which are incomparable. It would be a great help.

Comment: @mb14 I'll give you a concrete representation of this lattice and maybe it helps. Let $$X=\{\varnothing,\mathbb N\}\cup\{\{n\}:n\in\mathbb N\}.$$ Then the lattice above is, up to isomorphism, $(X,\subseteq)$. Can you see why? If $n\neq m$ then $\{n\}$ and $\{m\}$ are incomparable under $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 3):

For any infinite set $X$,

1. $\mathcal P(X)$, the lattice of subsets of $X$, is bounded with bounds $\varnothing$ and $X$,
2. $\Pi(X)$, the lattice of equivalence relations on $X$, is bounded with bounds $\Delta_X = \{(x,x):x\in X\}$ and $\nabla_X = \{(x,y):x,y\in X\}$,